# cURL command line or lib - resume of file download - IIS

Tags: shell, curl, libcurl

I'm having some troubles with libcurl. The problem I'm seeing when i try to resume a download of a file that was already downloaded. But in some cases I do not know if it was downloaded or not, so we try to re-download with continue, which fails with HTTP 416 - server does not support byte ranges.

This is definitly not true as the sever can continue at any point up until the file is downloaded.

Is there a way that libcurl would know that a file is infact already downloaded and not give this misleading error?

Or can i somehow otherwise chec if it is downloaded completely?

```html
~ # ./curl -L -O -C - http://speedtest.ftp.otenet.gr/files/test10Mb.db
sk_sort:0xb6f4eae4
** Resuming transfer from byte position 10485760
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (33) HTTP server doesn't seem to support byte ranges. Cannot resume.

~ # ls -ltr test10Mb.db
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root      10485760 Aug  9 09:13 test10Mb.db
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, libcurl *could* make a **HEAD** request first to figure out what the total size is *before* it asks for the range request, so it would see that it already has all the data downloaded and skip the next request.

That would of course add a funny race condition that would make a file that is growing on the server end easily falsely trigger such "no need to resume" errors.

In your case, you can probably work around your problem by manually adding such a HEAD request before your resume attempt.

Comment: Would it be probably best to tweak with IIS to return the content length in 416 which will notify curl that infact download is complete. Otherwise it is a bit useless to have continue... Or if curl would do this on 416 alone

Comment: Right, curl could perhaps do it for the 416 case but I'm not sure how sure curl can be that the reason is exactly that the entire thing already is downloaded... I'm open for patches for anyone willing to work on it!